# How can I publish downloaded npm dependencies to a private local repository?

Tags: node.js, npm, repository, publish, nexus

I'm currently setting up an node.js developing environment in a network without internet access.

I installed a nexus repository for storing the most common npm packages for the developers use.

I'm able to publish my own modules to this repo.

How I can publish these modules into the private repo?

Comment: what is the version of your nexus repository?

Comment: Nexus OSS 3.6.0-02

Answer (score 1):

You can publish 3rd modules with the npm command `npm publish` just set the publish registry in the `package.json` to the nexus url. For more information you can read this guide - [Use nexus as npm packages repository](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2017/02/14/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-2-npm-packages/)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to follow this steps:

- Create your local NPM repo in Artifactory.
  Replacing the default registry with your new local repository with this command:

  ```
  npm config set registry Http://<NEXUS_SERVER_DOMAIN>:8081/<PATH>/your-repo-name
  ```
- Deploy your packages to Artifactory. The first time you can upload the artifacts to artifactory manually or using this command in every project:

  ```
  npm publish --registry http://<NEXUS_SERVER_DOMAIN>:8081/<PATH>/your-repo-name
  ```